# Is it sound to use raw pointers to an allocated vector to allow multiple threads to write to nonoverlapping parts?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, unsafe, rayon

I have multiple threads doing a computation and want to collect the results into a pre-allocated vector. To turn off the borrow checker, I wrote the function:

```rust
fn set_unsync(vec: &Vec<usize>, idx: usize, val: usize) {
    let first_elem = vec.as_ptr() as *mut usize;
    unsafe { *first_elem.add(idx) = val }
}
```

With that we can fill a vector concurrently (e.g. using Rayon):

```rust
let vec = vec![0; 10];
(0..10).into_par_iter().for_each(|i| set_unsync(&vec, i, i));
```

It compiles, it works, and even Clippy likes it, but is it sound? After reading about things that appear to be sound but actually are Undefined Behavior, I'm unsure. For example, the documentation of the `as_ptr` method says:

> The caller must also ensure that the memory the pointer
> (non-transitively) points to is never written to (except inside an
> `UnsafeCell`) using this pointer or any pointer derived from it.

Strictly speaking, the solution violates this. However, it feels sound to me. If it is not, how can we let multiple threads write to nonoverlapping parts of the same vector without using locks?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248718/discussion-on-question-by-user1494080-is-it-sound-to-use-raw-pointers-to-an-allo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is your minimal reproducible example:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn set_unsync(vec: &Vec<usize>, idx: usize, val: usize) {
    let first_elem = vec.as_ptr() as *mut usize;
    unsafe { *first_elem.add(idx) = val }
}

fn main() {

    let input = vec![2, 3, 9];
    let output = vec![0; 100];
    input.par_iter().for_each(|&i| {
        for j in i * 10..(i + 1) * 10 {
            set_unsync(&output, j, i);
        }
    });

    dbg!(output);
}
```

If you are asking of whether this code works and always will work, then I'd answer with yes.

**BUT:** it violates many rules on how safe and unsafe code should interact with each other.

If you write a function that is **not** marked `unsafe`, you indicate that this method can be abused by users in any way possible without causing undefined behaviour (note that "users" here is not just other people, this also means your own code in safe sections). If you cannot guarantee this, you should mark it `unsafe`, requiring the caller of the function to mark the invocation as unsafe as well, because the caller then again has to make sure he is using your function correctly. And every point in your code that required a programmer to manually prove that it is free of undefined behaviour must require an `unsafe` as well. If it's possible to have sections that require a human to prove this, but do not require an `unsafe`, there is something unsound in your code.

In your case, the `set_unsync` function is **not** marked `unsafe`, but the following code causes undefined behaviour:

```rust
fn set_unsync(vec: &Vec<usize>, idx: usize, val: usize) {
    let first_elem = vec.as_ptr() as *mut usize;
    unsafe { *first_elem.add(idx) = val }
}

fn main() {
    let output = vec![0; 5];

    set_unsync(&output, 100000000000000, 42);

    dbg!(output);
}
```

Not that at no point in your `main` did you need an `unsafe`, and yet a segfault is happening here.

Now if you say "but `set_unsync` is not `pub`, so no one else can call it. And I, in my `par_iter`, have ensured that I am using it correctly" - then this is the best indicator that you should mark `set_unsync` as `unsafe`. The act of "having to ensure to use the function correctly" is more or less the definition of an `unsafe` function. `unsafe` doesn't mean it will break horribly, it just means that the caller has to manually make sure that he is using it correctly, because the compiler can't. It's unsafe *from the compiler's point of view*.

Here is an example of how your code could be rewritten in a more sound way.
I don't claim that it is 100% sound, because I haven't thought about it enough.
But I hope this demonstrates how to cleanly interface between safe and unsafe code:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

// mark as unsafe, as it's possible to provide parameters that
// cause undefined behaviour
unsafe fn set_unsync(vec: &[usize], idx: usize, val: usize) {
    let first_elem = vec.as_ptr() as *mut usize;

    // No need to use unsafe{} here, as the entire function is already unsafe
    *first_elem.add(idx) = val
}

// Does not need to be marked `unsafe` as no combination of parameters
// could cause undefined behaviour.
// Also note that output is marked `&mut`, which is also crucial.
// Mutating data behind a non-mutable reference is also considered undefined
// behaviour.
fn do_something(input: &[usize], output: &mut [usize]) {
    input.par_iter().for_each(|&i| {
        // This assert is crucial for soundness, otherwise an incorrect value
        // in `input` could cause an out-of-bounds access on `output`
        assert!((i + 1) * 10 <= output.len());

        for j in i * 10..(i + 1) * 10 {
            unsafe {
                // This is the critical point where we interface
                // from safe to unsafe code.
                // This call requires the programmer to manually verify that
                // `set_unsync` never gets called with dangerous parameters.
                set_unsync(&output, j, i);
            }
        }
    });
}

fn main() {
    // note that we now have to declare output `mut`, as it should be
    let input = vec![2, 3, 9];
    let mut output = vec![0; 100];

    do_something(&input, &mut output);

    dbg!(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation.

Comment: A slightly more sound implementation that Miri likes, using `SyncUnsafeCell`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b6a44a57e365ea2ff633e1598c33d16). This never mutates behind an immutable reference or aliases a mutable reference and appears to be compatible with stacked borrows.

Comment: @PitaJ "Compatible with stacked borrows" - why isn't mine? Not criticizing, just curious :)

Comment: Yours triggers a MIRI warning for stacked borrows, I think because you mutate behind a shared reference without an UnsafeCell.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware there is a multithreaded version of `UnsafeCell`. Unfortunately, it's only available in nightly.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment at the top, it's available in stable via crates.io as well.